# SignalR Service Broker with data from SQL View, does it work? MVC 5 ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, signalr, service-broker

I've used SignalR with some Databases in SQL in my MVC 5 web application to update the Webpage when table data is modified. My question is...

Can I use a MessagesRepository that uses a SqlCommand to a SQL View? Does a SQL View fire a Service Broker event? I'm very new to SignalR and just wanted to know if I could use my SQL Views or if I needed to copy the views query into the Message Repository or not.

If you need some code for examples, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately views are explicitly called out as invalid in [Special Considerations When Using Query Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewzkxxh(v=vs.80).aspx):

> - The statement must reference a base table.
> - The statement must not reference a view.

Before you move the view definition up into the client app, you need to make sure the query in the view is a valid query for QN, see the restrictions above.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for. Must have been googling the wrong stuff! :)